# Is Active Directory access needed in Azure in order to create a Kubernetes Service?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, active-directory, azure-aks, azureportal

My company created a subscription within our Azure tenant, and my account has an Owner role within that subscription. I'm trying to create a Kubernetes cluster, but I apparently don't have permissions to create the required service principal as part of the kubernetes creation wizard. I also tried with the `az` CLI tool and received a similar message:

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac
```

which responds with: Directory permission is needed for the current user to register the application. For how to configure, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal

When I go to the Active Directory page on the portal, I also get an "Access denied" message.

My question is, should the Global Admin for our AZ tenant create the application for me and give me access to use it, or as a subscription Owner should I have access to Azure Active Directory in order to create my own applications and service principals ?

Or is there a way for me to create a Kubernetes cluster without having Active Directory access ?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you need to have a service principle:

> To interact with Azure APIs, an AKS cluster requires an Azure Active Directory (AD) service principal. The service principal is needed to dynamically create and manage other Azure resources such as an Azure load balancer or container registry (ACR).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-service-principal